# How to recreate image slide-in effect from apple.com/ipod-nano

Tags: jquery, webkit

I noticed a nice slide-in effect on the apple website. As you scroll down the page and the images become visible (slide into view). http://www.apple.com/ipod-nano

I am trying to isolate the key scripts involved. I took the nano page code into dreamweaver to investigate. It appears to be a custom Javascript `onscroll` event combined with a `-webkit-` CSS modifier.

The problem is that there are so many linked `.js` files that I am having trouble cutting through the clutter to see the key code involved. There are many linked pages that I'm sure are just taking care of the smoothness and minor detail.

What do I need to do to recreate this functionality? Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this in jQuery is to track the window's scroll position using [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop) and compare it to a DOM element's position using [`.offset().top`](http://api.jquery.com/offset).

When they are equal, the DOM element has reached the top of the browser window. Or you can add a constant number of pixels or [`$(window).height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height) to detect when it's just coming into view.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/LtMgP/ -- scroll the page and watch for the word "marker", which will switch from black to blue partway up the page. Code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('p').offset().top-100) {
        $('p').css('color','blue'); 
    };
});​
```

Comment: Cool thanks so much Blazemo.. does anyone know how to then trigger a slide in event like on the apple site example? I know there are ways with webkit but am not sure how to create a similar effect with $ Or trigger the -webkit- via -$-